# Could not find or load main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, mainclass

i am getting error **"Could not find or load main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar"** in my android studio 3.0.1. i know it's kind of duplicate question but i had look for proper solution but i didn't get solution. I had tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) but i didn't understand what's the proper solution. so, please anyone can help me to fix this issue? Full error statement i am getting is as follow.
**Error**

```
    Error:Could not find or load main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {@H:\AndroidStudio\PerfectPhotoEditor2018\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args3374109584933962673}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for Java 8 support in your build.gradle file [inside compile option block] and disable (comment or delete) it then try to clean and rebuild the project.